# Firefox not displaying LaTex (via MathJax)

Tags: networking, latex

I'm using Firefox 23.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bits. I'm having problems with seeing math formulas on [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

I went to the MathJax website and there I can see the ML but not the LaTeX. <del>I think this is an Ubuntu problem, since I can see everything well on a Mac and on Windows (using Firefox).</del>  I've tried to start Firefox in safemode to make sure it's not an add-on or extension issue, and the problem persisted.

*I've tried other machines on the same network, and they had the same problem. I've also tried one of them on a different network and everything worked fine. **Therefore, I now believe this is a network problem and not an Ubuntu problem.** I still have no idea what can be causing it, and wold very much welcome some ideas, but this question should be closed.*

*My apologies.*

---

**EDIT**: (I've posted the problem on MathJax users group with links to here). Here's a summary of what I've recently tried: I've cleared Firefox's cache, prevented it from using DNS, flushed DNS from my OS (with dns-clean command on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit), started Firefox in safemode and the problem persisted. I've completely reset my router and configured a new wireless network and the problem is still there! Any ideas?

Comment: GLG can you split this up into two questions? It would make the title much more descriptive if each title was more specific. Thanks!

Comment: I can report that my Firefox 23.0 under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (32bits) shows correctly LaTeX formulas both in math.stackexchange.com and in mathjax.org

Comment: Please, I'd appreciate even a guess of where to look (which configuration, what documentations, etc.); since I don't have any ideas.

Comment: Could you provide a list of all the tex/latex you have installed? `dpkg --get-selections | grep tex > installed-tex`

Comment: @GLG, you say, this seems to be related to the network you're on. Could it be some firewall, proxy (e.g., privoxy) etc issue? On one of my networks at work we had webwasher installed that would clean the pages of some unwanted images and scripts...

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox: install the [Greasemonkey extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/), then install the userscript: [display-latex2.user.js](http://alexeev.org/display-latex2.user.js), which is an adaptation of the original userscript [display-latex.user.js](http://www.gold-saucer.org/mathml/greasemonkey/).

Also take a look at [A Greasemonkey user script to display LaTeX on Web pages](http://www.gold-saucer.org/mathml/greasemonkey/)

Answer (score 0):

When you display a page with LaTeX written with MathJax in a browser, the javascript in the page will try to call MathJax web site for web fonts which are used to display the LaTeX equations. It seems that your network has stopped MathJax from doing that.

A workaround is to install STIX fonts in your machine so that when MathJax cannot locate the web fonts, it will start to look for local fonts in your machine. You may refer the link below for reference.

http://www.mathjax.org/help/fonts/

I hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've looked and `fonts-stix is already the newest version.` The link didn't mention any other steps I needed to take, so I guess that's not it?

Comment: How about to work in the reverse way, that is to remove the fonts-stix from you machine and to see whether the MathJax can call the web fonts for display? Beware that this method remove the installation of fonts-stix from the system and therefore may be destructive!

Comment: Thanks. Okay, I've successfully removed it. Unfortunately, the problem still persists. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to boot your machine with a liveCD or liveUSB having Ubuntu on it. After the desktop comes out, use the Firefox on the clean machine to visit MathJax.org. If LaTaX comes out correctly, the problem should not be caused by the network.

Comment: Clever! Alas, I'm writing this from the clean machine and I'm experiencing the very same problem.